# Pytest skipping a test class that inherits from a builtin

Tags: pytest

**TLTR**:
The question is maximally easy: Please look at the code base case. Pytest just ignoring this class. **How I should run tests on a such class**?

I just started switching from a simple python tests (with just `assert`) to testing with pytest and come across with this problem. Most of my tests is are classes that extending a real classes with test methods. One of my classes inherit from `collections.UserDict`. Pytest just ignoring this class. **How I should run tests on a such class**?

```
# Inheritance from object are ok, Inheritance from dict are not ok. Need dict :(
class TestFoo(dict):

    def test_foo(self):
        assert 1
```

output:

```
/home/david/PycharmProjects/proj/venv/bin/python /snap/pycharm-professional/302/plugins/python/helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiprocess --qt-support=auto --client 127.0.0.1 --port 44145 --file /snap/pycharm-professional/302/plugins/python/helpers/pycharm/_jb_pytest_runner.py --path /home/david/PycharmProjects/proj/tests/unit_tests_2.py 
Testing started at 11:07 ...
Launching pytest with arguments /home/david/PycharmProjects/proj/tests/unit_tests_2.py --no-header --no-summary -q in /home/david/PycharmProjects/proj/tests

============================= test session starts ==============================
collecting ... collected 0 items

============================= 2 warnings in 0.03s ==============================

Process finished with exit code 5

Empty suite
```

**UPD** Thanks for @Teejay Bruno, running tests from pycharm hiding a warning from me:
`PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestFoo' because it has a __init__ constructor`

Answer (score 1):

The warning tells you the problem:

```
PytestCollectionWarning: cannot collect test class 'TestFoo' because it has a __init__ constructor
```

If I understand what you're trying to do, why not just pass the object as a fixture?

```
import pytest

@pytest.fixture
def my_dict():
    return dict()

class TestFoo:

    def test_foo(self, my_dict):
        assert len(my_dict) == 0
```

Comment: Thanks, that's helped me. But I'm still wondering what is the reason of such behavior.
P.S.: No, I'm don't getting any warning, see the updated question.

Comment: I would recommend reviewing the pytest docs -- https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/getting-started.html

In short, a test class is not a normal class meant to be instantiated -- it's essentially just a namespace. It's intended purpose is for grouping related tests together in order to easily apply `fixtures`, `markers`, or executing from the cli.